# How do I give the value of a child function to another, outside the parent function scope

Tags: javascript

Let's call the parent function `exo()` and the nested one `childexo()`.

I need to parse the value of a result from `childexo()` to another function outside both `exo()` and `childexo()`, let's call that one, `newFunc()`.

The note here should be that, I need to get the value of the result of `childexo()` and not the `exo()` function.

```
function exo(){
  // SOME CALCULATIONS

  return childexo = function() {
    const Itext = "Phew, you just killed your bug";
    console.log(Itext);
  }
}

exo();

function newFunc(childexo) {
  // SOME CALCULATIONS

  var xImagine = function() {
    console.log(childexo);
  }
}

newFunc(childexo);
```

I noticed `childexo` can't be put like this `childexo()` as the `newFunc` parameter.

I just need the console.log of `childexo()` to be displayed instead of displaying the function `childexo()` in console like `outterHTML`.

I'm new to JavaScript, so I may only understand simple codes.

Comment: Your `exo()` function returns a value (the function you want to call), but you don't save that value anywhere.

Comment: How do I save it?

Comment: `let childexo = exo();`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I answered about the same way when this was asked (and then closed by the OP) yesterday.

The function `exo` returns another function. It needn't be named inside `exo` since the caller can assign it to a variable.

Another function, `newFunc`, can certainly take a function as param. You can "mention" a function just by using the variable name to which it is assigned. You can "invoke" that function by placing an argument list after it in parens `()`.

Here's the OP code restated (with errors removed) in ES6 style...

```js
const exo = () => {
  //SOME CALCULATIONS
  return () => {
    var Itext = "Phew, you just killed your bug";
    console.log(Itext);
  }
}

const newFunc = childexo => {
  //SOME CALCULATIONS
  // here we "invoke" the passed function. this can be done inside
  // yet another function as the OP attempts, but ultimately we must invoke
  childexo();
}

// this is what @Pointy meant by "saving" the returned function
let fnFromExo = exo();  
newFunc(fnFromExo);
```

Comment: Wow, now I understand. But on line 9, you didn't cover `childexo` with `()` or is it because it's a function?

Comment: On the declaration of `newFunc`? That's  called a parameter or "dummy parameter" it's just a name we made up to represent the value that is passed to newFunc

Answer (score 1):

what you want is ....

1. exo() will return subfunction
   so you need to save somewhere ('asdf')

```
function exo(){
  //SOME CALCULATIONS
  return function(){
    var Itext;
    Itext.textContent = "Phew, you just killed your bug";
    console.log(Itext);
  }
}
var asdf = exo();
```

do not assign something at return.

it is unneccessary

2. newFunc will execute given function
   so you need to call function.

```
function newFunc(exoArgs){
  //SOME CALCULATIONS
  var xImagine = function(){
    console.log(exoArgs());
  }
}
newFunc(asdf);
```

but childexo is return void, so console.log of newFunc will print ''
you will get

```
Phew, you just killed your bug
   // empty line
```

Comment: console.log(exoArgs()); returns `undefined`.

Comment: What I'd do is: function exo(){
  //SOME CALCULATIONS
  return function(){
    var Itext;
    Itext.textContent = "Phew, you just killed your bug";
    console.log(Itext); return Itext;
  }
}
var asdf = exo();

Comment: you need to save return value of exo. I saved it at asdf. it is used at newFunc.